# web audio filter response

Tags: filter, web-audio-api

I have a simple filter.

```
var filter = ctx.createBiquadFilter();
filter.type = 'highpass';
filter.frequency.setValueAtTime(10,ctx.currentTime);
```

I would like to see its frequency response using `getFrequencyResponse`

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    var frequencyHz = new Float32Array(1),
        magResponse = new Float32Array(1),
        phaseResponse = new Float32Array(1);
    frequencyHz[0] = 10;
    filter.getFrequencyResponse(frequencyHz,magResponse,phaseResponse);
    console.log(magResponse);
},100);
```

I expect to see `[0.9565200805664062]` which is the correct response for 10Hz, but instead I see `[0.0008162903832271695]` which is the response for 350Hz, the default frequency value.
I can only get a sensible response if I manually set the value, whereas if I use param methods such as `setValueAtTime`, the filter response ignores them and spits out the default. In other words, `getFrequencyResponse` seems to only work if the filter values are set manually, preventing filter analysis when the values are set by automation. If this is true, this seems like more than a small problem with the api.

Someone please try something near to this, and if it works (doubtful) please post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no, it should be taking effect, but because you're causing an instantaneous value change at the NEXT processing block (that's what ".currentTime" means), that change has not yet been processed - so you're seeing the default value.  You should see, for example, getFrequencyResponse changes over time for a setLinearRamp.

Comment: I've tried linearRamp as well with no luck. I'm viewing the response data multiple times using a time interval, so regardless of the param type I use, it should be processed and I should see the effect at some point. Try it.

Comment: Oh hey Chris, didn't realize it was you. thanks for taking the time to  follow the link if that's how you got here.